# Any way to restrict the usage of Authorization Header forked from a web site's request from network tab in developer tools

Tags: reactjs, .net, authentication, jwt, authorization

The problem : I deveoped an JWT authentications service that issues Authorization Header. This header value /token is then sent along with all web-requests. This authentication library wILL be used by a React App too.
Now, One can easily inspect the site and check all request related data and get the authorization token.

How can I restrict its usage , or from being used by an attacker as discussed above.

I know people combine things like User-Agent/Ip address too to make the token more user-specific
I want to know if there are any other tools too that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Any browser API message credential works the same way and can be intercepted by the user and replayed using HTTP tools. Eg if a browser based app uses an HTTP-only cookie as a backend credential, the user can get that also, and send it using tools.

**PERMISSIONS**

The main thing to do is to ensure that backend authorization only allows the JWT access token to do things the user can do in the app anyway. So if I can view my purchases in the UI, then I can do the same thing via an API call, but I should not be able to elevate my privileges:

```bash
curl http://api.example.com/purchases \
-H "Authorization: Bearer eyJraWQiOiIyV01TWGcwekEydVFlTjE ..."
```

**CONFIDENTIALITY**

Another concern might be that the user can read the contents of the JWT, for example the `name`, `email`, `role` etc. Note also that if the JWT contains such personal information, it can end up in the browser history or server logs, which could be raised as a PEN test issue.

For this reason it is considered more secure to return an unreadable token to the front end. Eg an HTTP-only cookie. The [OAuth for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) doc has some recommendations. When access tokens are returned to the browser there are also cross site scripting threats, where HTTP-only cookies are usually perceived to have fewer risks.